# Is there a way for ul to stretch out of the modal

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So I have a combo boxes done with ul/li which open when you click on an anchor. My issue is that it's part of a modal dialog (jquery-ui) and the dialog itself has only 2-3 elements so it's rather small. My combo boxes have around ~12 elements (it's variable really) so it's actually bigger than the modal window itself.

So right now, when I open the combobox it add a scroll to the dialog. Is there a way for the element to somewhat stretch out of the dialog?

Or a suggestion on how to make this dialog be a little more intuitive? :)

Here's the html:

```
<div id="select">
<a id="combo">combo</a>
<div id="combul_div">
<ul id="comboul">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<a id="click">Click</a>
```

Here's the js I use

```
$('#click').click(function () {
$('#select').dialog({ 
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    position: 'center'
 });
});

$('#combo').click(function() {
    $('#comboul').toggle();   
})
```

Here's the css I'm using:

```
#select {
 display: none;
}
#combo {
    width: 100px;
}
#comboul_div{
    width: 100px;
}
#comboul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of a trimmed down version: http://jsfiddle.net/cspHy/7/

Comment: Why do you need to use `#comboul { position: absolute; }`? What's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/cspHy/6/ ?

Comment: That would move the rest of the dialog around (like button below) I would like to keep them at the same place. Basically I would like to mimic the way a select behave (be on top on the dialog)

I added a select to my example so that people can see:
http://jsfiddle.net/cspHy/7/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cspHy/8/ See the top of the css frame. You should limit these rules to apply only to your special dialog(s).

Comment: Yes this is what I want! I was trying the overflow:visible on ui-dialog directly! Post your solution as a solution and i'll accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy now :) BTW I used my browser's inspector feature to investigate this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@biziclop has provided the right solution.

Just to put an answer here,

## CSS

```
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

#select {
 display: none;
}
#combo {
    width: 100px;
}
#comboul_div{
    width: 100px;
}
#comboul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

`#comboul` can be positioned absolutely OR can be made `float :left`